# Calling a native function from within an inner class

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, inner-classes

I have a native function, I can call it without error from my Activity. It is declared as a (non static) method of myActivity.

I tried to call it from within an inner class (a Thread) :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        MyActivity.this.nativeFunction();
    }
  }).start();
```

I have the error native method was not found. Please note that I can call nativeFunction directly from myActivity (it has the full qualified name of myActivity)

Comment: show more code and full crash report

Comment: Compilation error? Linkage error? NB the inner class here is an *anonymous* inner class, and it is a Runnable, not a Thread.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try doing it like that ?

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //call the native function
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Why? How would that solve the problem? What *is* the problem?